# rdesktop request without gui linux

Tags: linux, rdp

Can I make rdesktop request without installed x-server?

Just send RDP request from linux (Centos 6) server to windows server?

When I run:

```
rdesktop -uUSER -pPASS host:port
```

the error appears:

```
ERROR: Failed to open display:
```

Solve the problem with install xserver, and freerdp may be it helps someone (centos 6):

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
startx
export DISPLAY=localhost:0
yum install freerdp
xfreerdp -u USER -p PASS --ignore-certificate HOST
```

Comment: What sense does the protocol make without any installed graphics output? What do you want to access that way? Sorry, that makes no sense... You could either login with ssh or similar to get access on CLI level or you could try to fire an application on the remote system and have it connect to your local X server by means of X11 forwarding. But the rdesktop protocol is to forward a remote graphical desktop which clearly does not exist in your case.

Comment: maybe you could explain what you are actually trying to achieve, maybe you are on the wrong path with rdp

Comment: only send rdp request, another it manager said it's only that he need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have several options:

- Use a client that render over framebuffer, for  instance [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/)
- Install a X-Server on your desktop machine, for  Windows do you have [XMing](http://www.straightrunning.com/xmingnotes/). To redirect your X you must define `DISPLAY=<ip_x_server>`

Comment: Do you have an example of using FreeRDP over framebuffer?